# Extracting values from xml file into field delimiter format using unix script/command

Tags: xml, shell, unix, xml-parsing

Here is sample file and we need to convert values into delimiter formatted file :-

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <testjar>

 <testable>
 <trigger>Trigger1</trigger>
 <message>2012-06-14T00:03.54</message>
 <sales-info>
 <san-a>no</san-a>
 <san-b>no</san-b>
 <san-c>no</san-c>
 </sales-info>
 </testable>


  <testable>
  <trigger>Trigger2</trigger>
  <message>2012-06-15T00:03.54</message>
  <sales-info>
  <san-a>yes</san-a>
  <san-b>yes</san-b>
  <san-c>no</san-c>
  </sales-info>
 </testable>

 </testjar>
```

Each record should start on new line. Sample result set should be something like this 
sample.txt

```
Trigger1|2012-06-14T00:03.54|no|no|no  
Trigger2|2012-06-15T00:03.54|yes|yes|no
```

Note :- xmlstarlet is not installed on my server, is it possible to perform this without xmlstarlet?

Comment: Please fix `<message->`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) installed, you can try:

```
me@home$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//testable" -v trigger -o "|" -v message -o "|" -m sales-info -v san-a -o "|" -v san-b -o "|" -v san-c -n test.xml
Trigger1|2012-06-14T00:03.54|no|no|no
Trigger2|2012-06-15T00:03.54|yes|yes|no
```

Breakdown of the command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t 
    -m "//testable"       # match <testable>
      -v trigger -o "|"     # print out value of <trigger> followed by |
      -v message -o "|"     # print out value of <message> followed by | 
      -m sales-info         # match <sales-info>
        -v san-a -o "|"       # print out value of <san-a> followed by |
        -v san-b -o "|"       # print out value of <san-b> followed by | 
        -v san-c              # print out value of <san-c>
    -n                   # print new line
    test.xml             # INPUT XML FILE
```

To target tags that varies within `<testable>`, you can try the following which returns the text of all leaf nodes:

```
ma@home$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//testable" -m "descendant::*[not(*)]" -v 'text()' -i 'not(position()=last())' -o '|' -b -b -n test.xml 
Trigger1|2012-06-14T00:03.54|no|no|no
Trigger2|2012-06-15T00:03.54|yes|yes|no
```

Beakdown of the command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t 
    -m "//testable"                         # match <testable>
      -m "descendant::*[not(*)]"              # match all leaf nodes
        -v 'text()'                             # print text
        -i 'not(position()=last())' -o '|'      # print | if not last item
        -b -b                                   # break out of nested matches
    -n                                      # print new line
    test.xml                                # INPUT XML FILE
```

---

If you do not have access to `xmlstarlet`, then do look up what other tools you have at your disposal. Other options would include xsltproc (see [mzjn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664831/extracting-values-from-xml-file-into-field-delimiter-format-using-unix-script-co/11665754#11665754)) and [xpath](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/p/xpath).

If those tools are not available, I would suggest using a higher level language (Python, Perl) which gives you access to a proper XML library.

While it is possible to parse it manually using `regex`, such a solution would not be ideal<sup><sup>[†](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)</sup></sup> especially with inconsistent inputs. For example, the following (assuming you have `gawk` and `sed`) takes your input and should spits out the expected output:

```
me@home$ gawk 'match($0, />(.*)</, a){printf("%s|",a[1])} /<\/testable>/{print ""}' test.xml | sed 's/.$//'
Trigger1|2012-06-14T00:03.54|no|no|no
Trigger2|2012-06-15T00:03.54|yes|yes|no
```

However, this would fail miserably if the input format changes and is therefore **not a solution I would generally recommend**.

Comment: catch here is my file(xml tages will increase or decrease)will keep changing..is there a command which can take care of this?

Comment: Do you mean the tags within `<testable>` is always different?

Comment: Yeah.. but we can store tages in another file and fetch that info here...we can manage that.. Big issue is unfortunately I dont have xmlstarlet at my server :-( Can this be possible without xmlstarlet?

Comment: What OS are you using? And are you allowed to install additional tools from the default package manager? (I'm trying to avoid a regex/text-parsing approach here since it can be unreliable especially if the input format is not consistent)

Comment: Linux version 2.6.9-100.ELsmp. I m not allowed to install additional tools. Thanks

Comment: @PravinSatav I'm assuming That's a Red Hat? I'm afraid it's difficult to provide an ideal solution without knowing what tools you have and don't have.

Comment: @PravinSatav See updated question for an example that uses gawk and sed (note the disclaimer in the text).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XSLT stylesheet that does what you want (saved in test.xsl):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="testable">
   <xsl:value-of select='trigger'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select='message'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select='sales-info/san-a'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select='sales-info/san-b'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select='sales-info/san-c'/><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Command (here I am assuming that you have libxml2 and libxslt installed; [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/xslt/xsltproc2.html) is a command line tool that uses these libraries):

```
xsltproc -o sample.txt test.xsl test.xml
```

Contents of sample.txt:

```
Trigger1|2012-06-14T00:03.54|no|no|no
Trigger2|2012-06-15T00:03.54|yes|yes|no
```

Comment: xmlstarlet is not installed at my server.. Is it possible to without xmlstarlet?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure bash solution:

```
egrep '<trigger>|<message>|<san-.>' test.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | while read line; do [ $((++i % 5)) -ne 0 ] && echo -n "$line|" || echo $line ; done
```

However, it only works on a file formatted as in your sample (each element in a separate row), it's not even closely as flexible / reliable as the other answers involving proper XML parsing / transforming.

It can be enhanced to some extent though...