# Command line tool to extract key value pairs from XML files

Tags: xml, unix, xml-parsing, utilities

Quite regularly I need to extract key value pairs from XML files. Is there an easy-to-use UNIX(-style) command line tool available for this?

#### Example case

The XML file looks like this:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>BlackPointCompensation</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Export A</string>
        <key>WatermarkSettings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DGOperationClassName</key>
            <string>DGImageCompositeScaledOperation</string>
            <key>inputKeys</key>
            <dict>
                <key>inputCompositeImagePath</key>
                <string>/Users/me/imageA.psd</string>
                <key>inputOpacity</key>
                <real>0.94999999999999996</real>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>BlackPointCompensation</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Export B</string>
        <key>WatermarkSettings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DGOperationClassName</key>
            <string>DGImageCompositeScaledOperation</string>
            <key>inputKeys</key>
            <dict>
                <key>inputCompositeImagePath</key>
                <string>/Users/me/imageB.psd</string>
                <key>inputOpacity</key>
                <real>0.70</real>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

For this file I want to construct a command line command with the ("key" tag) parameter `"inputCompositeImagePath"` which prints the ("string" tag) values `/Users/me/imageA.psd` and `/Users/me/imageB.psd`.

What's a good tool for this kind of operations? I had a brief look at `xmllint`, but it doesn't seem to be well suited for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through another stackoverflow answer ([Extracting values from XML file...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664831/extracting-values-from-xml-file-into-field-delimiter-format-using-unix-script-co),) I came a cross the command line tool `xmlstarlet` (Download at [xmlstar.sourceforge.net](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), tutorial at [www.geekfarm.org](http://www.geekfarm.org/wu/muse/XmlStarlet.html)) which is able to do the job:

Say, the XML file is saved as preset `preset-test.xml`. Then use in your shell

```
xml el preset-test.xml
```

to get an overview over the XML structure. Then type

```
xml sel -t -c "(//string[preceding-sibling::key[1] = 'inputCompositeImagePath'])/text()" preset-test.xml
# (blank line for firefox rendering of stackoverflow code class)
```

to extract the wanted information. It prints as expected:

```
/Users/me/imageA.psd
/Users/me/imageB.psd
```

*Note:* The magic is obviously in the XPath expression `(//string[preceding-sibling::key[1] = 'inputCompositeImagePath'])/text()`. It works as follows:

1. `//string[...]` selects all tags with the name `string`, but
2. `preceding-sibling::key[1] = 'inputCompositeImagePath'` restricts this selection to tags where the first *preceding sibling* has the value `'inputCompositeImagePath'`.
3. `/text()` than selects from this selection the textual content.

The `xmlstarlet` tool is maybe not as easy to use as I hoped for, but due to its full XPath functionality pretty powerful.